# Why do I get the error: 'awk: read error (Is a directory)'

Tags: c, linux, awk, pipe, fork

I am unsure where the error is in my code. I intended on piping the output of one child process to a parent process and then piping the output of that to the find child. The program compiles but I receive the error : awk: read error (Is a directory), the intent of the program is to read the file size of the desired directory using the ls -al function along with the awk function. These values are then piped to the ./adder program which sums the values together. The output should be the addition of the file sizes.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define INPUT 1
#define OUTPUT 0
#define STDIN 0
#define STDOUT 1

int main(void){

int awk2adderPFD[2];
pid_t pid , pid2;
pid = fork();
pipe(awk2adderPFD);
if( pid == 0) { //must be child
close(awk2adderPFD[OUTPUT]); //close read end of pipe
dup2(awk2adderPFD[INPUT], STDOUT); //fd1 points to write end
close(awk2adderPFD[INPUT]); //close pfd[1] as no longer used
execlp("./adder","./adder", (char *)0) ; 
    }
    else { 
        int ls2awkPFD[2];
            pipe(ls2awkPFD);
            pid2 = fork();
        if( pid2 == 0) { //must be child
        close(ls2awkPFD[OUTPUT]); //close read end of pipe
        dup2(ls2awkPFD[INPUT], STDOUT); //fd1 points to write end
        close(ls2awkPFD[INPUT]); //close pfd[1] as no longer used
        execlp("ls", "ls","-al", (char *) 0);
            
        }
        else { //parent process
            close(ls2awkPFD[INPUT]); //close write end of pipe
            dup2(ls2awkPFD[OUTPUT], STDIN); //pfd0 points to read end
            close(ls2awkPFD[OUTPUT]); //close pfd[0] of parent
            execlp("awk", "awk", "-F:",  "{ print $5 }", "/home/adeyemo/assignment2.1", (char *) 0);
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: so is `/home/adeyemo/assignment2.1` a directory?

Comment: Yes, thats the directory i am trying to get the file size from.

Comment: If you're trying to do `ls -al directory | awk...` to add up the file sizes then don't. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Comment: My guess is that you have a directory called `awk` in the directory you are running the program from. Try recoding the `execlp` to run `/usr/bin/awk`, or whatever the absolute path is

Comment: There are only the two programs and the executables within the directory. From my understanding what I have to do from the website provided https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs  I need to parse the information correctly so the awk command can select the fifth field to execute the adder program.

Comment: This was the directory listing in case you were wondering : https://prnt.sc/w2sjxd